# What's wrong with my PHP for loop?

Tags: php, html

What's wrong with my PHP loop?
It just loops until it eventually times out.

```
$max = 7;
$derp = $a / 5;
for($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++){
if($i = $derp){
echo"<option value='$derp' selected='selected'>$derp</option>";
}else{
echo"<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
}
```

Comment: For comparison you need to give == instead of =

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
if($i = $derp){
```

to

```
if($i == $derp){
```

As you are currently assigning it, not comparing.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

Comment: Ah sorry, been coding too much java i guess

Comment: 12:25 am?
I've been coding for years. I feel embarrassed now.

Comment: We all make mistakes, and there's always something new to learn no matter how long we've been in the game (this is one of the reasons I love programming).  No need to feel embarrassed :)

Answer (score 1):

`if($i = $derp)` should be `if($i == $derp)`

Answer (score 1):

`=` assigns a value to a variable. `==` compares for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$max = 7;
$derp = $a / 5;
for($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++){
if($i == $derp){
echo"<option value='$derp' selected='selected'>$derp</option>";
}else{
echo"<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
}
```

In your code you are trying to assign a `$derp` to `$i`.If you want to compare it change it as
`if($i == $derp)`.